# TypeError: Cannot read property 'notesObjectInService' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to load in my controller an object that should be available in my service(factory) notesFactory.

However the controller is not being able to identify the injected service at all. You can look at the statement console.log(typeof notesFactory) that returns ‘undefined’, therefore notesObjectInService triggers the exception.

I don’t know what I am missing. I don’t think it’s just a typing mistake ( I reviewed the code several times), but I’m new to javascript and AngularJS so I might be missing something. I wondered whether the problem could live in the postPromise, but I still struggle to understand exactly how the promises work.

If someone knows the answer for this problem I’d be very thankful.

```
 function NotesProvider(){
    this.$get= angular.noop
}
angular.module('theNotesApp2',['ui.router'])
     .config(['$stateProvider',
              '$urlRouterProvider',
              function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
                  $stateProvider
                      .state('home', {
                          url: '',
                          //the templateUrl value is the id for the routing
                          templateUrl: '/home.html',
                          controller: 'mainCtrl',
                          resolve: {
                              postPromise: ['notesFactory', function(notesFactory){
                                  return notesFactory.getAll();
                              }]
                          }
                      })
                      .state('navbar',{
                          url: '/navbar',
                          templateUrl: '/navbar.html',
                          controller: 'mainCtrl'
                      })
                      .state('notes',{
                          url: '/notes/{id}',
                          templateUrl: '/notes.html',
                          controller: 'notesCtrl'
                      });
                  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
              }
     ])

     .factory('notesFactory', NotesProvider,'$http' [function($http, NotesProvider){

        var notas = {notesObjectInService: []};

        notas.getAll() = function() {
             return $http.get('/notes.json').success(function(data){
                 angular.copy(data, notas.notesObjectInService);
             })
        };
        notas.create() = function(note){
            return $http.post('/notes.json', note).success(function(data){
                notas.notesObjectInService.push(data);
            })
        };

        return notas;
     }])

    .controller('mainCtrl',['$scope', 'notesFactory', function($scope, notesFactory){
        console.log(typeof notesFactory);
        $scope.notes = notesFactory.notesObjectInService;

        $scope.addNote = function(){
             if ($scope.title === "" ) {
                 return;
             }
             notesFactory.create({
                 title: $scope.title,
                 body:$scope.body
             });
             $scope.title= '';
             $scope.body= '';
         };
     }])
    .controller('notesCtrl', ['$scope', 'notesFactory', '$stateParams', function(
         $scope, notesFactory, $stateParams){
         console.log('test');
         $scope.note =
             notesFactory.notesObjectInService[$stateParams.id]
     }])
```

[image]

Comment: methinks here error `.factory('notesFactory', NotesProvider,'$http' [function($http, NotesProvider){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problematic place. First of all you confused array notation in factory definition and the order of injected services.

Then object method definition should be just without `()` after method name:

```
notas.getAll = function () { /* ... */ };
```

Correct factory definition would look like:

```
.factory('notesFactory', ['$http', 'NotesProvider', function ($http, NotesProvider) {

    var notas = {
        notesObjectInService: []
    };

    notas.getAll = function () {
        return $http.get('/notes.json').success(function (data) {
            angular.copy(data, notas.notesObjectInService);
        })
    };
    notas.create = function (note) {
        return $http.post('/notes.json', note).success(function (data) {
            notas.notesObjectInService.push(data);
        })
    };

    return notas;
}]);
```

Comment: thanks  @dfsq It solved the problem. I had not realised that silly mistake I was making. Also once the array notation properly done the 'NotesProvider' became pointless and the code works fine now.